# How to find new coordinates with initial coordinate and distance?

Tags: location, coordinates

If I have initial coordinates, coord0 = [29.205,-93.4683], and a distance of 10km, how do I find the coordinate 10 km to the left of -93.4683, the coordinate 10km south of 29.205, and the coordinate that is both 10km south and 10 km left? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question might have been more relevant on the GIS Stack Exchange.

I assume that the coordinates you give are a latitude and a longitude. As you want to compute an offset in kilometers and that this offset is pretty small, the simplest way is to convert the values in UTM (which are values in meters), do the translation in UTM and convert again to a latitude and a longitude. For the sake of this example, I used the Python library `utm` do compute the transformations.

`utm.from_latlon(29.205,-93.4683)` gives the transformation of the coordinates in UTM. The geographical location is located in the tile `15R` and give as a result the following coordinates `(454477.6336829163, 3230788.981221904)` in the order `(easting, northing)`. As said above, these coordinates are in meters.

10km left means 10km west given the geographical location and the translation in UTM can be computed as `454477.6336829163 - 10000 = 444477.6336829163`.

10km south, for the northern hemisphere in UTM means `3230788.981221904 - 10000 = 3220788.981221904`

With respect to the location, the translated position is still located in the `15R` UTM tile, therefore the reverse transform to latitude, longitude can be computed with:

`utm.to_latlon(444477.6336829163, 3220788.981221904, 15, 'R')` which returns `(29.11434747694546, -93.5706694557042)`.

One can see that this result makes sense. The latitude is slightly smaller as we are a bit more south and the longitude a bit more negative as we are a bit more west.